# Find the volume inside the paraboloid $x^2+4z^2+8y=16$ and on the positive side of x-z plane.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

$$V=2\int_0^4\int_0^{{(16-x^2)}/8}\sqrt{4-\frac{x^2}{4}-{2y}{}}\,dy\,dx$$

i have change this question in above way by taking limit of y and x. is it corect ?? also i'm not getting how to solve this integral without changing it into polar form.

what region does the question referring to when it says positive side of xz plane?

Comment: The $x$-$z$ plane is surely the plane $y=0$, and its "positive side" is the points with $y>0$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown thanxx.. for solving the integral am i supposed to use formula of integral sqrt(a^2-x^2) ?? but here in place of x^2 i have 2y. so how am i supposed to proceed?

Comment: To parametrize the region $0 < y < 2 - x^2/8 - z^2/2$, take $(x, y, z) = (4 r \cos t, y, 2 r \sin t)$ (consider the region $0 < 2 - x^2/8 - z^2/2$ in the $xz$-plane first). Your double integral is correct, but it gives $1/4$ of the volume, not $1/2$.

Comment: @Maxim thanxx for reply.. but i'm not getting why it gives 1/4th of volume and not 1/2 as i'm integrating x from 0 to 4 instead of -4 to 4

Comment: It doesn't include the part where $z$ is negative.

Comment: @Maxim but i'm not integrating it wrt z so how am i'm taking negative z into consideration. i'm not getting it? could you please help me in visualising the area which is supposed to be integrated?